# Highchart map not loaded - Angular & proj4

Tags: angular, highcharts, proj4js

I'm trying to load a map chart using highchart but the map won't display. The map seems to be properly loaded.
I'm using Angular and it's officiel highchart wrapper. Also proj4 is needed to have lat & long maps data.

I've done a stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-maps-proj4

Thank's a lot :)

Comment: Map is coming. What is the problem ?

Comment: Well the map is not displayed, only the bubbles are

Comment: I see the following error after launching the demo: `Error in src/app/app.component.ts (19:27) Cannot find name 'HighchartMaps'.` Try changing `this.Highcharts = HighchartMaps(Highcharts);` to `this.Highcharts = Highcharts;` Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-maps-proj4-cf9nqx?file=src/app/app.component.ts